# How to avoid null result of "SELECT max(rank) FROM test" for an empty table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to form an query in JPQL (2.0) to select a the max value (rank).

I use: `SELECT max(rank) FROM test`

This works fine, except the case where the table is empty, then the result is `null`, but I need `0`.

*This would be no problem if I was able to "catch" the null with an simple if-statement, but I can't do this (the framework allows only to specify an JPA Query but no java code).*

Does anybody have an idea how to tune that query to get an `0` instead of an `null` if the table is empty? - The database is an MySQL, and native queries or stored procedures are no option.

Comment: Cause it's a native query (I suppose that JPQL does not allow to COALESCE like that)

Comment: No native queries, no stored proc, you can't do a simple `if (ret == null) ret = 0;` kind of thing. I'm curious, why all the restrictions? Feels like you are deliberately tying your hands behind your back.

Comment: can you use count(*) before this query, for a workaround.

Comment: @pap: the restrictions are because of the framework and the environment.

Comment: @Nitin Chhajer: sorry, an other restriction is, that I can only configure a single query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(rank), 0) FROM test
```

**EDIT**

`COALESCE` seems supported by JPQL (JPA 2.0): http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part3.html

Comment: 10 seconds quicker than me :)